# Python: can't catch an IndexError

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

Disclaimer: this looks like a duplicate, but finding an answer to this particular problem was more than trivial - I hope others will find this question/answer with more ease!

When I run the following code, it fails to catch the second IndexError, raising it instead:

```
try:
  raise ValueError
except ValueError,IndexError:
  pass
l = [1,2,3]
try:
  l[4]
except IndexError:
  print "an index error!"
```

results in

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-61bcf6d2b9af> in <module>()
      6       pass
      7 try:
----> 8       l[4]
      9 except IndexError:
     10       print "an index error!"

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 30):

The problem was bad use of `except ...` syntax. The line:

```
except ValueError,IndexError:
```

should be

```
except (ValueError,IndexError):
```

*Explanation*: If you want to inspect the exception that was thrown, the syntax is `except <exception-class>,e` where variable `e` is assigned an instance of `<exception-class>`. Here's what happens in the failing code:

1. `open("afile",'x')` throws a `ValueError` as `'x'` isn't a valid file mode string.
2. `except ValueError,IndexError` assigns the thrown `ValueError` instance to a new variable called `IndexError`.
3. **This new variable overrides the builtin `IndexError` class.**
4. `l[4]` raises an actual `IndexError` exception.
5. The `except` clause is checked for this exception type, but only an instance of `ValueError` (which happens to have the name `IndexError`) is found, so the exception is not caught.

If you are running an interactive python session, you can `del IndexError` to uncover the builtin and allow you to catch `IndexError`'s again.

Comment: This is fixed in Python 3 where the syntax for `except` statements has been changed from `except X, T` to `except X as T`.