# How to ignore IndexError in while/for loops?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find index of value "1.2 Information" in table.

Where's only one value like this, and it could be at any column.
I need to get index of row with this value.
I got this code to find it, but I get IndexError in first column.
How to ignore error and continue loop?

I know that I can do this with 'continue', can't understand how.

```
ind = ""
cols = list(df.columns)
while type(ind) != int:
    for col in cols:
        ind = int(df[df[col].str.contains('^1.2 Information') == True].index[0])
```

[Table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YfbBDom1ISKPRIvkBa6oqnsc426ghzk3/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113752785996722037226&rtpof=true&sd=true)

```
01.01.* - 31.12.*                                                   
1.1                                                 
No.     No.     Date 1      Time                    
1231    46546               21:15:27                    
                                                    
        No.     No.         Date 1      Time                
        789798  45648                   15:20:38            
                                                    
        1.2 Information
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an example dataframe that replicates the problem

Comment: Catch the error inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Where's only one column without error. I need to let loop work and ignore error before get index of row with this value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: can't catch an IndexError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24230324/python-cant-catch-an-indexerror)

Comment: I think, I got another decision for problem, without loops.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple decision for this task:

```
int(df[df.isin(['1.2 Information ']).any(axis = 1)].index[0])
```

There's no need for loops, And this code will be quite fast.